# R ggplot : join point by

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to visualize data by using ggplot2, but instead of joining the dots directly, I'd like to join the dots **like in the 2nd example** of this image :

[image: Dots Joining]

**Question : How can I do that with ggplot2 ?**

Edit : Your solution works well user20650 but the lines don't appear straight when I plot them into a pdf :

[image]

**Do you know why ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_step` should work here. The `direction="vh"` directs the steps to vertical first then horizontal

```
# Some example data
dat <- data.frame(x = 0:2, y=c(3,1,2))

library(ggplot2)  

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_step(direction="vh")
```

Comment: It works well but the lines are not really straight !
Do you know why ?

Comment: hmmm, they look straight for me when i save to pdf. Can you share the code used to create the image in your edit please.